# Modifying Format File using Python

Tags: python, sql

I have a Format File of above format say `"test.fmt"`. I have to remove the entire third row and the last row ie. `Id` and `Flag` row from the file. Meanwhile, also update the column number on the LHS. For eg. in this case after removing the two columns, I will get 5 rows remaining. This value '`5`' must also be updated in row 2 which is currently '`7`'. Also notice how the last row in output file has a "`\r\n`", so need to change that too.

How do i go about this using python(it will be very helpful if someone could help with a sample code or something), and also parameterize the variable to do the same task for 50 files with different number of rows.

Comment: you could use `pandas` to read it as `read_csv(filename, sep="\s+")` and work much easier with `DataFrame`. Only two first lines you would have to read normally.

Answer (score 0):

You could read first two rows in normal way and rest read using `pandas.read_csv(..., sep="\s+")`

I use `io.StringIO` only to simulate file but you should use `open()`

```
data = '''14.0
7
1       SQLCHAR             0       12      ","      1     Id                               ""
2       SQLCHAR             0       200     ","      2     value1                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       200     ","      3     value2                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR             0       200     ","      4     value3                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR             0       200     ","      5     value4                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR             0       200     ","      6     value5                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR             0       12      "\r\n"   7     Flag                              ""'''

import pandas as pd
import io

# open file for reading    
fh = io.StringIO(data)
#fh = open(filename)

# read first two line    
two_lines = [next(fh), next(fh)]
print(two_lines)

# read rest as CSV file without headers
df = pd.read_csv(fh, sep="\s+", header=None)
print(df)

# skip rows which have `Id` or `Flag` in 7th column
df = df[ ~df[6].str.contains('Id|Flag') ]

# assign new values in first column
df[0] = range(1, len(df)+1)

#print(df)

# open file for writing
fh = open('output.txt', 'w')

# write first two lines 
fh.write(two_lines[0])
fh.write(str(len(df)) + '\n')

# if you don't need spaces then you can use this
#df.to_csv(fh, sep=' ', index=False, header=False)

# if you need spaces then you can use this

for row in df.itertuples():
    # format line to keep spaces
    line = '{:<8}{:<20}{:<8}{:<9}{:<8}{:<6}{:<28}{}'.format(*row[1:])

    #print(line)

    # write line
    fh.write(line + '\n')

# close file
fh.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should preserve the original fmt file layout using the `re.split()` and skip/renumber the fields as requested:

```
import re
SKIP_WORDS = ['Id', 'Flag']
LAST_LINE_CRLF = r'"\r\n"'

with open('test.fmt') as input_file:
    vers = next(input_file).strip()
    _ = next(input_file)

    new_lines, new_field_no = [], 0
    for line in input_file:
        if not any(s in line for s in SKIP_WORDS):
            new_field_no += 1
            data = re.split(r'( +(?=.*))', line.strip())
            data[0] = str(new_field_no)  # renumber field
            data[10] = str(new_field_no)  # renumber field
            new_lines.append(data)


with open('test_new.fmt', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(vers + '\n')
    output_file.write(str(new_field_no) + '\n')

    for idx, line in enumerate(new_lines, start=1):
        if idx == new_field_no:  # adjust last line delimiter
            line[8] = LAST_LINE_CRLF
            line[9] = '   '
        output_file.write(''.join(line) + '\n')
```